# Create new column in data frame based on formula stored in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame where I stored a formula, which may vary by row. This formula calls on other columns in my data frame, and I would like to create a new column in my data frame that applies the formula that I have stored in the formula column, but I am not sure how to go about it. I tried `eval()` and `mutate()` but they are just copying over the text of the formula and not grabbing the values of the columns it specifies and applying it.

For example, the `formula` column below contains the formula for the new column I want to create. The `output` column in my "want" data frame is the values I would get after applying the formulas stored in the `formula` column to each row.

```
#create sample dataset
dog<-c(1,1,1,1,0,2)
cat<-c(1,1,0,1,1,4)
formula<-c("dog","dog+cat","cat-dog","cat","cat-dog","dog")
have<-as.data.frame(cbind(dog,cat,formula))

  dog cat formula
   1   1     dog
   1   1 dog+cat
   1   0 cat-dog
   1   1     cat
   0   1 cat-dog
   2   4     dog

# want

  dog cat formula output
   1   1     dog      1
   1   1 dog+cat      2
   1   0 cat-dog     -1
   1   1     cat      1
   0   1 cat-dog      1
   2   4     dog      2
```

Comment: You could create a function that hosts the different equations and use logic to apply them based on row-values. It would be the easiest way, and you would only need to update the function if your needs change.

Comment: It’s generally a bad idea to evaluate strings as code for various reasons. Where is this data coming from? Do you *have* to store it as strings? R is a very dynamic language and allows you to construct expressions flexibly at runtime *without* having to store them as strings, and doing so is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Do not use `cbind` when creating dataframes. Just do `have <- data.frame(dog, cat, formula)`. Note that this maintains the datatype, while cbind messes up the data.types

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
have %>% 
  mutate(dog = as.integer(dog),
         cat = as.integer(cat)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(output = eval(parse(text=formula)))


    dog   cat formula output
  <int> <int> <chr>    <int>
1     1     1 dog          1
2     1     1 dog+cat      2
3     1     0 cat-dog     -1
4     1     1 cat          1
5     0     1 cat-dog      1
6     2     4 dog          2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `tapply` with `str2lang` or `str2expression`:

```
have$output <- tapply(have, seq(nrow(have)), \(x) eval(str2lang(x$formula), x))
have
  dog cat formula output
1   1   1     dog      1
2   1   1 dog+cat      2
3   1   0 cat-dog     -1
4   1   1     cat      1
5   0   1 cat-dog      1
6   2   4     dog      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
have$dog <- as.numeric(have$dog)
have$cat <- as.numeric(have$cat)
for (i in 1:4){dog <-have$dog[i]
               cat <- have$cat[i]
               have$eval[i] <-eval(parse(text = have$formula[i]))}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't think so, since I am creating a `dog` and `cat` variable at each step of the loop? This step overwrites the vectors `cat` and `dog` at the first iteration.

Comment: Ah, right, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `mapply`.

```
> transform(have, 
+           out=mapply(\(x, y) eval(parse(text=x), envir=y), 
+                      have$formula, 
+                      split(have, seq_len(nrow(have))))
+ )
  dog cat formula out
1   1   1     dog   1
2   1   1 dog+cat   2
3   1   0 cat-dog  -1
4   1   1     cat   1
5   0   1 cat-dog   1
6   2   4     dog   2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(have)
structure(list(dog = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2), cat = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 4), formula = c("dog", "dog+cat", "cat-dog", "cat", "cat-dog", 
"dog")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```